# Map legend with CSS

Tags: css

How would you style a legend map with css only (no images)?

Do I use div element for little squares of color or a span element?

Something like this: http://golondrinas.cornell.edu/Maps/Map%20legend.png

Comment: You mean, a real map's legend? Not the `<legend>` element?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. A real map legend.

Comment: did *any* of these answers help you? Or are there still problems with which we could assist?

Comment: I used a bunch of divs, and css - it aligned nicely and was easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever you want. There's no best practice for this rather rare example.

The description "a coloured box" fits a `div` best I think. `span` would usually mean something inline, but could work as well, seeing as there is one per line, so to speak. You would have to make it `inline-block`, which isn't supported in all browsers, or `block`, but a `div` is block by default, so no hassle with that. With a `div` however you would need to possibly `float` it, i'm not quite sure. With both you'd have to set the `width`.

So to summarize, there's none that is better than the other, but `div` would be more semantically correct, since `span` should usually contain something that it "spans".

Comment: Cross-browser inline-block: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Answer (score 9):

I'd personally use a definition list:

```
dt {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
.aqua {background-color: aqua; color: aqua; }
.orange {background-color: #f90; color: #f90; }
.black {background-color: #000; color: #000; }

dd {
display: inline-block;
width: 15em;
margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}


<dl>
<dt class="aqua">Aqua</dt>
<dd>T. bicolor range</dd>
<dt class="black">Black</dt>
<dd>T. thalassina range</dd>
<dt class="orange">Orange</dt>
<dd>T. euchrysea range</dd>
</dl>
```

I'm not sure it's any more semantic than [@Tor Valamo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630700/map-legend-with-css/3630721#3630721)'s answer, but it feels like it makes more sense to me.

---

**Edited** to add link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/umije3) demo in response to comment by OP.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to make sure that dt aligns with dd (on the same line)? Right now dd is displayed underneath it.

Comment: Oooh, yeah, forgot about `dl`... It's one of those things that some people overuse and some people don't use at all. I'm of the latter. :P

Comment: @Tor Valamo, there's that many tags and elements that forgetting `dl` is entirely understandable, but it did seem tailor-made for this purpose. :)